# c# manually binding data to gridview via stored procedure + parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview

I've been getting the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'GetActiveComissions' expects parameter '@param1', which was not supplied.

on the code line `da.Fill(dt)`. When I try to bind data to my GridView based on a stored procedure, clearly supplying the parameter.

Code:

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
string user = User.Identity.GetUserId();

string storedprocedure = "GetActiveComissions";
SqlConnection cn = GetSqlCon.GetCon();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedprocedure, cn); 
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", user);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);

GridViewActiveComissions.DataSource = dt;
GridViewActiveComissions.DataBind();
```

Could I be passing the parameter in a wrong way?

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetActiveComissions]
    @param1 nvarchar(128)
AS
    SELECT 
        Comissions.CreationDate, Comissions.Accepted, 
        Comissions.BicycleModel, Comissions.BicycleType, 
        Comissions.YearOfAquisition, Comissions.Details, 
        AspNetUsers.WorkshopName 
    FROM 
        Comissions 
    INNER JOIN 
        AspNetUsers ON Comissions.WorkshopId = AspNetUsers.Id 
                    AND Comissions.Accepted = 1 
                    AND Comissions.ClientId = @param1
    RETURN 0
```

I've tested the stored procedure separately and it does work as intended, given the parameter is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove '@' from parameter name, must be like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", user);
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("param1", user);

Comment: Comissions.ClientId, varchar or INT?

Comment: Same with that one.

Comment: It's a nvarchar(128)

Comment: check "user" for value, maybe "user" is empty or null

Comment: Got It working, apparently the user value was null if the code above was on the Page_Init function. Thanks